# Splitting an element of an array

Tags: c#, split

In my C# program (I'm new to C# so I hope that I'm doing things correctly), I'm trying to read in all of the lines from a text file, which will look something along the lines of this, but with more entries (these are fictional people so don't worry about privacy):

```
Logan Babbleton ID #: 0000011 108 Crest Circle Mr. Logan M. Babbleton 
Pittsburgh PA 15668 SSN: XXX-XX-XXXX
Current Program(s): Bachelor of Science in Cybersecurity
Mr. Carter J. Bairn ID #: 0000012 21340 North Drive Mr. Carter Joseph Bairn 
Pittsburgh PA 15668 SSN: XXX-XX-XXXX
Current Program(s): Bachelor of Science in Computer Science
```

I have these lines read into an array, `concentrationArray` and want to find the lines that contain the word "Current", split them at the "(s): " in "Program(s): " and print the words that follow. I've done this earlier in my program, but splitting at an ID instead, like this:

```
nameLine = nameIDLine.Split(new string[] { "ID" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
```

However, whenever I attempt to do this, I get an error that my index is out of the bounds of my split array (not my `concentrationArray`). Here's what I currently have:

```
for (int i = 0; i < concentrationArray.Length; i++)
{
    if (concentrationArray[i].Contains("Current"))
    {
            lstTest.Items.Add(concentrationArray[i].Split(new string[] { "(s): " }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1]);
    }
}
```

Where I'm confused is that if I change the index to 0 instead of 1, it will print everything out perfectly, but it will print out the first half, instead of the second half, which is what I want. What am I doing wrong? Any feedback is greatly appreciated since I'm fairly new at C# and would love to learn what I can. Thanks!

**Edit** - The only thing that I could think of was that maybe sometimes there wasn't anything after the string that I used to separate each element, but when I checked my text file, I found that was not the case and there is always something following the string used to separate.

Comment: You should check the result of split before tryijng to read at index 1. If your line doesn't contain a "(s): " your code will crash with the exception given

Comment: @Steve why would it work if I used 0 as my index instead of 1 though?

Comment: It works because if there is no separator the output is an array with a single element containing the whole unsplitted string

Comment: @Steve oh okay, I didn't see that whenever I read through the split method notes. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the result of split before trying to read at index 1.
If your line doesn't contain a "(s): " your code will crash with the exception given

```
for (int i = 0; i < concentrationArray.Length; i++)
{
    if (concentrationArray[i].Contains("Current"))
    {
         string[] result = concentrationArray[i].Split(new string[] { "(s): " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
         if(result.Length > 1)
             lstTest.Items.Add(result[1]);
         else
             Console.WriteLine($"Line {i} has no (s): followeed by a space");
    }
}
```

To complete the answer, if you always use index 0 then there is no error because when no separator is present in the input string then the output is an array with a single element containing the whole unsplitted string

Comment: You can also print the entire line to see what it looks like. This can be very useful. Or maybe at least the line number, if you can keep track of these while you're iterating.

Comment: That worked, thanks! I didn't think to check to see if all lines containing Current also contained the split string, because they should've, I just missed one.

Answer (score 1):

If the line will always starts with

```
Current Program(s):
```

then why don't you just replace it with empty string like this:

```
concentrationArray[i].Replace("Current Program(s): ", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

It is perhaps a little easier to understand and more reusable if you separate the concerns. It will also be easier to test. An example might be...

```
var allLines = File.ReadLines(@"C:\your\file\path\data.txt");
var currentPrograms = ExtractCurrentPrograms(allLines);

if (currentPrograms.Any())
{
    lstTest.Items.AddRange(currentPrograms);
}
```

...

```
private static IEnumerable<string> ExtractCurrentPrograms(IEnumerable<string> lines)
{
    const string targetPhrase = "Current Program(s):";

    foreach (var line in lines.Where(l => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l)))
    {
        var index = line.IndexOf(targetPhrase);

        if (index >= 0)
        {
            var programIndex = index + targetPhrase.Length;
            var text = line.Substring(programIndex).Trim();

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
            {
                yield return text;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit different approach

```
            List<string> test = new List<string>();
            string pattern = "Current Program(s):";
            string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\xyz\Source\demo.txt");
            foreach (var line in allLines)
            {
                if (line.Contains(pattern))
                {
                    test.Add(line.Substring(line.IndexOf(pattern) + pattern.Length));
                }
            }
```

or

```
        string pattern = "Current Program(s):";
        lstTest.Items.AddRange(File.ReadLines(@"C:\Users\ODuritsyn\Source\demo.xml")
                .Where(line => line.Contains(pattern))
                .Select(line => line.Substring(line.IndexOf(pattern) + pattern.Length)));
```

Comment: Using `File.ReadAllLines` is potentially troublesome if the file is large. Better to use `File.ReadLines` and enumerate them.